# what are differences between Managed object model and Persistent object store?

Tags: core-data, persistent-object-store, nsmanagedobjectmodel

From apple CoreData framework docs,

**Managed object model:** A model allows Core Data to map from records in a persistent store to managed objects that you use in your application. Refer [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/DataManagement/Devpedia-CoreData/managedObjectModel.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010398-CH30-SW1).

**Persistent object store:** A persistent object store maps between objects in your application and records in a persistent store. Refer [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/DataManagement/Devpedia-CoreData/persistentObjectStore.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010398-CH31-SW1).

From these description, both are meaning the same that is mapping persistent store records with managed objects.

I would like to know what is the unique difference between Managed object model and Persistent object store.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The **managed object model** is an instance of `NSManagedObjectModel` and describes the *schema* used in your Core Data application.
It is loaded from the **model file** 
which contains all the entity descriptions with their attributes and relationships that
you defined in the Core Data Model inspector. So the model *describes* your objects.

The **persistent object store** is an instance of `NSPersistentStore`, which manages
the transactions to and from a **persistent store**, which is the repository where
the *actual data* is stored. In many cases, the persistent store is a SQLite file, but it can also be an XML file, a binary file or a "in-memory" store for temporary data.

The **persistent store coordinator** uses both: The `NSManagedObjectModel` and (one or more)
`NSPersistentStore`s, to load managed
objects from the store into the application and to write changed objects back into the store.

Comment: In apple docs, persistent store only represent the store containing the data of application(it may sqlite, XML or binary).  Please refer here, https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/DataManagement/Devpedia-CoreData/persistentStore.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010398-CH29-SW1

Comment: @Nandha: That document also says: *"Core Data also provides an in-memory store that lasts no longer than the lifetime of a process"*.

Comment: you said about Persistent store. But I would like to know about Persistent object store. Persistent store and Persistent object store, both are different. I think, isn't it?

Comment: @Nandha: No, "Persistent store" and "Persistent object store" are the same thing.

Comment: in apple docs, they given different description for "Persistent store" and "Persistent object store". If you get chance please refer the link which i gave in the first comment...

Comment: @Nandha: Now I see what you mean. If I understand it correctly, the "Persistent store" is the actual physical store file, e.g. the SQLite file. The "Persistent object store" is an instance of the NSPersistentStore class, which reads and writes to the store file.

Comment: Martin, 90%, we are thinking same and it seems correct. From our findings, The "Persistent object store" is an instance of the NSPersistentStore class, which reads and writes to the store file. Where as apple says, A persistent object store maps between objects in your application and records in a persistent store. is persistent object store mapping tool? or operation tool to handle/manage the records from external file?

Comment: @Nandha: I would say that NSPersistentStore reads/writes the records from external file, and that is what Apple means with "mapping objects".

Comment: Martin, I haven't 100% satisfy with this answer. So I am waiting for others answer. Hope u know that nothing wrong  in it.

Answer (score 1):

Regardless your question passed quite long, but it remains a clear concern which may help others to clarify & deep diving the topic. So, not go too far from Martin's answer, but take further explanation for you:

- Yes, Persistent Store and Persistent Object Store are totally 2 different matters

  - But No, Persistent Object Store IS NOT an instance of NSPersistentStore. Just somehow like Persistent Store, it's ONE file consisting of Classes which automatically declare by Xcode the paths / relations between Objects / Instances in the application and the bunches / blocks of code within the Persistent Store. Think of it like a file of hyperlinks (although it's much more complicated than that)
- Let think of Persistent Store as "DataFile.xml / DataFile.sqlite / DataFile.customExtension, etc.". Because they are files, so all the records are stored as Script, Binary and so on. For example: < entityname > Transaction < /entity > OR < currency >USD< /currency > (No Space - Sorry that the website does not allow to add these (<...>))

  - The compilers (in this case XCode) can access, read and write to Persistent Store (files), but definitely require 2 things: (1) "translator" to decode from SCRIPT to OBJECT following the "instruction" of the "blueprint" Managed Object Model, (2) Like Managed Object Context is a temp place for Xcode working with Managed Objects before storing - Persistent Object Store play the similar role, but with SCRIPT & MODEL (provided by Managed Object Model) instead --> SO, THEY ARE THE ROLE OF PERSISTENT OBJECT STORE.

In practical programming, you don't even need to think of Persistent Object Store. It's an automatic process all which XCode takes. It's an abstract computing process rather than a specific concept or a specific stake (within Core Data Stack)

Referring to Apple's guide on Core Data (2011, Oct - quite old but remain active)
https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/content/documentation/DataManagement/Devpedia-CoreData/persistentObjectStore.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010398-CH31-SW1

--> "You don’t create a persistent object store directly. Instead, Core Data creates a store of the appropriate type for you when you send an addPersistentStoreWithType:configuration:URL:options:error: message to a persistent store coordinator."

Hope this helpful to you.